# How special method lookup works?

Tags: python

```
>>> class B():
...     pass
...
>>> class C(object):
...     pass
...
>>> b = B()
>>> b.__len__ = lambda: 7
>>> len(b)
7
>>> c = C()
>>> c.__len__ = lambda: 5
>>> len(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'C' has no len()
```

It is mentioned in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes), but I still don't understand how it works.

Comment: What exactly you didn't understand? Special methods are looked up in class instead of instance in new-style classes, hence the error for `len(c)`.

Comment: Yes, but how? Python interpreter maintain a list of special methods? Or all `__xxx__` methods are treated as special methods in Python 3?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like this magic is made by `type(x)`?